# QFileDialog paste default name

Tags: c++, qt, savefiledialog, qfiledialog

I was wondering either it is possible in Qt, when executing a file dialog, to paste a default highlighted name value already for "saving as", before user gives hes own. I Was not able to find this property.

[image]

I would appreciate all help!

Answer (score 2):

I have found the answer, the method is [void QFileDialog::selectFile(const QString & filename)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfiledialog.html#selectFile)

Comment: was about to post that .)